# Is it possible to tell Android to leave a little room with adjustPan

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, adjustpan

My app is set to `adjustPan` when the soft keyboard covers a text box. My boss likes it, but he wants the Pan to leave a little extra room between the text box and the keyboard. Currently the bottom of the text box and the top of the keyboard touch. Is there anyway to tell Android to leave a bit of space?